# For future reference, I have a red Volvo

Tags: meaning, interpretation

Here's from a TV show "3rd Rock from the Sun"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKeXnzoc0pI

6:04

> For future reference, I have a red Volvo.
>   Please, Dr. Albright! We barely know each other.
>   (laugh)

I wonder why it's funny.
Well, I got a wild guess, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very much like she said the following:

> For future reference, I have a red **vulva**.

This refers to her having excited genitals.

The show revolves around the misunderstandings of the aliens in their interactions with humans, thus the laugh.